# Is it possible to access a real API in React Storybook

Tags: storybook

I am using Storybook to test my React UI components.

However, when I get to a point where my Action makes an Axios request, I get a 404 response.

Below is the code used in a react action file:

assume the axios instantiation, thunk implementation and action definitions.

```
    getDelayedThunkRes: () => {
        return (dispatch) => {
            dispatch(delayedResActions.getInitialRes());
            axios.get("/test").then(success => {
                console.log(success);
            }).then(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
        }
    }
```

localhost:8080 is my real server that I want to connect to. Obviously it should throw me an error because my storybook is running on 9009. How can I connect the two?

Note, it works for my Create React App. Create React App package gives a provision to proxy all the calls to a server using "proxy" field in package.json

Are there any similar tools in Storybook, or is Storybook supposed to be used solely with static mock data?

Comment: I haven't had any issues accessing any API from Storybook. Please add some additional details to reproduce this issue, especially code.

Comment: @zero298 Example code added.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, I found an amazing post on how to create a middleware for React storybook for APIs
https://medium.com/@wathmal/adding-a-router-middle-ware-to-react-storybook-4d2585b09fc

Please visit the link. The guy deserves the due credit.

Here is my implementation of it in ES5 (somehow Storybook middleware is unable to transpile):

create this middleware.js inside .storybook directory:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const expressMiddleWare = function(router) {
    router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
    router.use(bodyParser.json());
    router.get('/test', function(req, res) {
        res.send('Hello World!');
        res.end();
    });
}

module.exports = expressMiddleWare
```

**Caveat: You will have to restart Storybook every time you make a change in the middleware.**

With this, I am able to make a call from my react actions.

Next, I will try to implement express HTTP proxy middleware to redirect these storybook middleware calls to my real express server.

**Edit 1:**

The new technique seems to be using decorators, especially with stroybook-addon-headless.
[Storybook add on for setting server urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58710353/storybook-add-on-for-setting-server-urls)

https://github.com/ArrayKnight/storybook-addon-headless

I am yet to try